# Variable overwritten with nil in each iterator

Tags: ruby

I simplified the problem I've got with following code:

```
def self.foo()
    array = [0,3,5,10,4,6,9,7]

    array.each do |arrayelement|
        name = "Ruts" if arrayelement == 5
        puts name
    end 
end
```

When a certain element of the array equals a constant, a string should be written in the variabele. Every element in the array is unique. The problem is that it writes "Ruts" into variable name when arrayelement = 5, but in the next iteration of the each loop it overwrites it with nil. Here's the output of the method.

```
nil
nil
Ruts
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
```

How can I change my code so variable name = Ruts instead of nil for the next iterations?

Comment: The variable is local to the block. If you want it to preserve state, declare it outside and above the loop.

Comment: @Santhosh It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the variable `name` is local to the block and gets defined every time. Just declare it outside.

```
name = nil
array.each do |arrayelement|
  name = "Ruts" if arrayelement == 5
  puts name
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code can be modified as follows:

```
name = nil
array.each do |arrayelement|
  name = "Ruts" if !name && arrayelement == 5
  puts name
end 

name
#=> "Ruts"
```

However same thing can be achieved much more efficiently like this:

```
name = 'Ruts' if array.include?(5)
#=> "Ruts"
```